# Android device on MTP shows up as "Unnamed Device"

Tags: nautilus, android, mtp, nemo

I have a Nexus 5. Ubuntu detects and mounts it fine, and I have no problem in transferring files or any other action. However, it does show up as an "Unnamed Device" in some places (Ubuntu 14.04, both cases):

- Nemo (with Gnome Shell)
  [image: Gnome Shell and Nemo]
- Nautilus (with Unity, fresh install)
  [image: Unity and Nautilus]

How do I assign a name to it?
I recall seeing the same behaviour on older versions as well, so I think this is not specific to 14.04. And it also happens with other devices: https://askubuntu.com/questions/370551/ubuntu-13-10-nexus-7-is-mounted-as-an-unnamed-device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a particular name property provided by the device through MTP, and this is the value you are seeing here. On a nexus device, it's always empty - so you see Unnamed Device. For other kinds of Android device, you may see a meaningful value here (I think Samsung set it). It's actually possible to set from the PC side using MTP but there's no way to expose this in Nautilus - as you see, none of the things you can click on have this name - the 'Nexus 5' you see comes from the USB identifier - I couldn't tell you why Nautilus uses different information in different places.